# Why is NSCalendarDate in the Simulator SDK but not in the iPhone SDK?

Tags: iphone, calendar, date

I want to use NSCalendarDate, which exists in

> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator2.2.1.sdk/
>   System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Headers/NSCalendarDate.h

but is not present anywhere under

> /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform

What gives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After 10.5 [`NSCalendarDate`](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendarDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) will be deprecated. Thus it likely just doesn't exist in iPhone SDK:

> Important: Use of NSCalendarDate
>   strongly discouraged. It is not
>   deprecated yet, however it may be in
>   the next major OS release after Mac OS
>   X v10.5. For calendrical calculations,
>   you should use suitable combinations
>   of NSCalendar, NSDate, and
>   NSDateComponents, as described in
>   [Calendars](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendars.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003470) in [Date and Time Programming
>   Guide for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000039i).

Look for the iPhone versions of [`NSCalendar`](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/Reference/NSCalendar.html), [`NSDate`](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [`NSDateComponents`](https://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSDateComponents)

Answer (score 0):

I only see NSCalendar referenced in the API docs.  I would bet this is either unpublished (and therefore unsupported) or deprecated.